# I am trying to get real time data stock price in my android app, is it possible with retrofit to get real time data

Tags: android, socket.io, retrofit

I am trying to develop a trading  APP which shows the live stock. 
I have API's for that, I have tried with retrofit library 
but the problem is the value I want show (Stock price) is changing at server side 
but no changes in my app. so I need to observe data changes at server.

Comment: No, you need to implement socket communication in order to achieve real-time changes.

Comment: do you have sample code

Comment: i have tried socket.io but am getting connection error

Comment: which error? can you post error log?

Comment: That's not about Retrofit, that's about sync your app with server data. So you should use e.g. WorkManager for periodic synchronization.